# You have an error in your SQL syntax EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following line of sql code:

```
,sum(if(extract(year_month from x.now_date) = extract(year_month from @chosen_date- interval 1 month) ,1,0)) as Now
```

that results to this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ,sum(if(extract(year_month from x.now_date) =
> extract(year_mont'..

I tried to check the sql version of the server but I couldn't see what is the error.

Comment: this is not complete query. why there is `select , ` and what is `x.now_date`

Comment: If the error is at the `sum()` then it is occurring *before* this line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is before this line of code.  The error message shows the code where the parser is getting confused.  It does not necessarily include the code that causes the error.

In any case, you can simplify the logic:

```
sum(extract(year_month from x.now_date) = 
    extract(year_month from @chosen_date - interval 1 month)
   ) as Now
```

That is, the `if()` is not needed in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

use mysql syntax, you have taged mysql but uses different syntax

```
sum(if(year(x.now_date) = year(DATE_SUB(@chosen_date,interval 1 month)) ,1,0)) as Now
```

Comment: @mars share you full query i corrected the portion that you shared